# DataSets Tutorials

Tags: c#, dataset

I'm currently in the planning phase of a project and I came across an interesting question (for me) - how the f* do DataSets work anyway?

I mean, since now I always used simple SQL-Statements written hard in the code, but that doesn't seem so sophisticated to me. So basically I want to start using DataSets but there are no tutorials out there concerning that. I mean, sure I can design them in VS, but how can I access them in my code? I searched a whole day long but couldn't find a single useful tutorial to that...

Is it because DataSets are no good or just because nobody uses them?

I would be very thankful for any information concerning that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd be interested in the first few tutorials at [Microsoft's ASP.NET Data Access Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials) page.  The tutorials there guide you through creating a simple ASP.NET site that features accessing data in the Northwind database (SQL Server 2005).

It does a decent job creating, configuring and using Typed DataSets.

Comment: +1. I'd accept this answer. Scott michell did a great job on the dataset tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Datasets are important part of ADO.NET, and works like in-memory objects and widely used. You can store more than 1 table in DataSet, and apply some relationship among them if needed. Also it works both in reading and writing the data while DataReader is only for reading teh data.

You can go for this link for better understanding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(VS.71).aspx